How to show Graphite timer upper value correctly with larger time window
I have a timer metric.  If I zoom in to the graph, e.g. taking just an hour, or half hour of data, the upper value shows correctly as 27,000.  When I look at more time, e.g. 2 hours, the upper value is "incorrectly" reduced.
Is there way to configure graphite to show the true upper/lower/mean values?  Links to documentation / tutorials would be gratefully received, I'm not sure how to phrase my question to ask it correctly.  I see a similar unresolved discussion about Graphana here.  I don't think it's to do with Whipser / storage as the data is clearly there.  It's more a Graphite presentation issue I think?
2 hours (peak to right has maximum of 17,000):

1 hour (same peak has correct maximum of 27,000):

